# Resolving tasks in VSTS / VSO (Agile Template)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, kanban, tfs-process-template

I have created a new project in VSTS (Visual Studio Online) using the Agile Template.

I have created a sprint, and added a user-story. Within the user-story I have some tasks.

On the sprint Kanban board there are 4 columns;

- New
- Active
- Resolved
- Closed

I can move tasks from **New** to **Active**, but cannot move them from **Active** to **Resolved**.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This confusing behavior is because the Agile Template shows both Bugs and Tasks on the same board view. While Tasks have a New -> Active -> Closed workflow, bugs have an additional Resolved step.

Your task should transition directly from Active to Closed.

You bugs will be able to rest a bit in the Resolved column before being dragged all the way to Closed.

Answer (score 11):

To recall your question:

*I can move tasks from **New** to **Active**, but cannot move them from **Active** to **Resolved**.*

This is also not a problem in Azure DevOps but the standard process (Agile workflow states). The following are the steps that can be used for the workflow in the standard process:

- **User Story** (New, Active, Removed, Resolved, Closed)
- **Bug** (New, Active, Resolved, Closed)
- **Task** (New, Active, Removed, Closed)

[image]

In Azure DevOps, however, this workflow can be adapted. For this the process must be modified. Here you can also add **Resolved** for a task within the workflow. Role "Collection administrator" is needed.

via *Organization settings / Boards / Process / Agile (default) ... Create inherited process*

Further information and picture source under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/agile-process-workflow?view=vsts

and https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#create-inherited-process

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create an inherited Process from Agile template as explained here:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/process/manage-process#create-inherited-process
Then , you can simple Hide the "Resolved" state for Bugs from your workflow as shown here:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/process/customize-process-workflow
That's it! the column is gone from your Task Board!
Moreover: you can now add your own States and Columns.
Good luck!
Michael